# sending post request in flask

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send post request in flask.

I'd like to send json object with `Content-Type: application/json` set as a header.

I'm doing this with *requests* module as follows:

```
json_fcm_data = {"data":[{'key':app.config['FCM_APP_TOKEN']}], "notification":[{'title':'Wyslalem cos z serwera', 'body':'Me'}], "to":User.query.filter_by(id=2).first().fcm_token}
json_string = json.dumps(json_fcm_data)
print json_string
res = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', json=json_string)
```

But this gives me:

> TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'

Any advices on how to fix this?

Comment: pass `data=json_string`

Comment: but do it set "Content-Type: application/json"?

Comment: there are 3 attributes, `headers`, `param` and `data`. To set headers variable like `content-type` you should add that in headers attribute

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First fix the error:**

You need to change this:

```
res = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', json=json_string)
```

to this:

```
res = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data=json_string)
```

The error you are getting states that `requests.post` **cannot** accept an argument named `json`, but it accepts a keyword argument named `data`, which can be in json format.

**Then add your headers:**

If you want to send custom headers with the `requests` module, you can do it as follows:

```
headers = {'your_header_title': 'your_header'}
# In you case: headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post("your_url", headers=headers, data=your_data)
```

**To sum everything up:**

You need to fix your json formatting up a bit. A full solution will be:

```
json_data = {
    "data":{
        'key': app.config['FCM_APP_TOKEN']
    }, 
    "notification":{
        'title': 'Wyslalem cos z serwera', 
        'body': 'Me'
    }, 
    "to": User.query.filter_by(id=2).first().fcm_token
}

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(
    'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(json_data)
)
```

Comment: It seams it works <3 Thank you! Could you check if I'm doing the JSON object correctly? I'd like to get something like this:
{ "data" : 
  { 
  "key" : "value" 
  } 
"notification" : 
  { 
  "title" : "Hi", 
  "body": "ok" 
  }, 
"to" : "token" 
}

Comment: I have added a full solution on my answer, have a look!

Comment: "JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (d) at position 0.\n"

Comment: Yeah my bad, `json.dumps` is needed after-all

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: No problem mate :)